# Separate street name from street number

Tags: php, python, regex, preg-replace

I am trying to separate street names from street numbers which have these patterns:

1. "street 12"  --- name:street , number:12
2. "street12"   --- name:street , number:12
3. "street 12a" --- name:street ,  number:12a
4. "street12a"  --- name:street , number:12a

What is the regex to get the street name, and the regex to get the street number in php and python?

Note: The number is always after the street name so I guess that should shorten it.

Thanks.

Comment: Can the following happen: `Strasse des 17. Juni 153`? (A valid street  address in Berlin, Germany)

Comment: In that case he should make it modular, so he can set a different regular expression for each country if he wanted. The tricky part is where you have streets that are numbers, like "32nd ST."

Comment: ... or 12, Avenue du 10ème de Ligne ...  Oversimplification will make the postman unhappy.

Comment: I wonder how search engines like google, bing, and yahoo do it?

Comment: your examples and written explanation should really provide a little more information about what needs to be matched - generally, though the expression `/^(?P<name>[a-zA-Z]+)\s*(?P<number>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/` will capture the name and number into *named* groups for the examples you provided. If the street name has more than one word, it becomes a little more complex, but still EASILY doable

Comment: @b01 "Search engines" generally don't bother parsing addresses. Now, if you're referring to *map* sites, on the other hand, (e.g. Google Maps, etc)... lots of finely-tuned geocoding code.

Comment: There's an "East Road" here in town as well. Regexes will NEVER be able to handle all street naming cases properly - they're just too randomish.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this as see if it works for you:

```
$subjects = array( "street 12", "street12", "street 12a", "street12a" );
foreach( $subjects as $subject )
{
    if ( preg_match('/([^\d]+)\s?(.+)/i', $subject, $result) )
    {
       var_dump( $result );
    }
}
die_r( $result  );
```

The only part you need is this:

```
// Find a match and store it in $result.
if ( preg_match('/([^\d]+)\s?(.+)/i', $subject, $result) )
{
    // $result[1] will have the steet name
    $streetName = $result[1];
    // and $result[2] is the number part. 
    $streetNumber = $result[2];
}
```

Comment: Glad to know I could help. I assume you're using this to correct a finite set of data, and not for the long term.

Comment: Best Solution found at https://gist.github.com/benvds/350404.  Cause this solution dont work at streetnames with number like "straße des 17 juni"

Answer (score 13):

I would suggest that the best way to determine when the number starts is when you hit a digit. Thus, you would use

```
preg_match('/^([^\d]*[^\d\s]) *(\d.*)$/', $address, $match)
```

Examples:

```
'Bubbletown 145' => 'Bubbletown', '145'
'Circlet56a' => 'Circle', '56a'
'Bloomfield Avenue 68' => 'Bloomfield Avenue', '68'
'Quibbit Ave       999a' => 'Quibbit Ave', '999a'
'Singletown551abc' => 'Singletown', '551abc'
```

It will probably be best for you to consider how you want edge cases to be handled, then write a unit test to test your own Regex function.

Answer (score 6):

Generally speaking, addresses are not always this clean. Especially if this data is coming straight from users, you have to consider that not everyone has such a standard address.  There are PO boxes, rural routes, `31 1/2`s, suites, tons of variations on street types (Road, Street, Circle, Court, etc, etc, plus all their abbreviations). Spaces in street names, hypens in house numbers, the complexity of addresses is very easy to underestimate. Mix in the potential for non-US addresses and the complexity goes up exponentially.

This giant function tries to make sense of all that (at least as far as the US Post is concerned): http://codepad.org/pkTdUDL6 I had this function kicking around, so it may need tweaking or elaboration. If nothing else, it should give you an idea of the task one is faced with when trying to make user address data sane.

This also makes it tempting to split the house number, street name, and street type into separate fields. If the accuracy of parsing addresses is critical to your system design, you might want to consider it; real estate systems for example would need to have this level of granularity for this data. If your use case does not critically rely on the ability to accurately parse this data, then I would not suggest presenting a user with all those extra fields. Just take their address as they give it, try to clean it up, and anticipate some inconsistencies in the rest of your system's design.

Comment: But he did state this the data he's using is always like this, I took that to mean he won't be using this in general.

Comment: I assumed that that statement was an assumption :)

Answer (score 4):

For street addresses in Germany the best working solution is https://gist.github.com/benvds/350404 (like @[ZFNerd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2462658/zfnerd) mentioned). Just do a little hack to detect "ß" character as well.

Instead of

> '#^([\w[:punct:] ]+) ([0-9]{1,5})([\w[:punct:]-/]*)$#';

you should use

> '#^([\w\ß[:punct:] ]+) ([0-9]{1,5})([\w[:punct:]-/]*)$#';

This solution works for streets like

- Dr.-Manfred-Hirschvogel-Straße 6
- Waitzinger Wiese 12
- Kirchenstr. 7
- Straße 150 13
- Magdeburger Allee 12a

perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Parsing street addresses can get nasty, really fast.  The most reliable, worry-free way is to use a service that can resolve the address components based on the full delivery point barcode (9-digit ZIP Code + 3-digit delivery point).

I work for an address verification company, [SmartyStreets](http://www.smartystreets.com) and we have an API that can parse these components for you.  See this [sample](https://smartystreets.com/docs/address#single).  Just a simple GET request and you've got a JSON result with all the address components parsed for you.

**Update**: SmartyStreets now provides [international address verification](https://smartystreets.com/docs/international).

Comment: FWIW, I use professionally and recommend Smarty Streets.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there can only be one final letter,

```
if (preg_match('/^(.+) *(\d+[a-z]?)$/', $address, $match)) {
   list($street, $number) = $match;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

May be old, but referring the comment from Pekka I would use following regex in b01 code:

```
/(.+?)\s?([\d]+[\D]*)$/i
```

so full code would be

```
// Find a match and store it in $result.
if ( preg_match('/(.+?)\s?([\d]+[\D]*)$/i', $subject, $result) )
{
    // $result[1] will have the steet name
    $streetName = $result[1];
    // and $result[2] is the number part. 
    $streetNumber = $result[2];
}
```

This selects the last occurring number including following chars (eg 15F/15 F) while still detecting streets including numbers (as 5th Ave 123, Straße des 17. Juni 123)