# Extracting street name and number

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database in which the address contains both street name and street number (and possible addition like A,B,C etc).

Now I need to split the street name, number and if available, the addition into separate fields (for a link with a logistics system).

Can anyone help me to achieve this? My experience with reg. expressions is 0.

Few possible examples could be:

> Stackstreet 14
>
> Stackstreet 14a
>
> Stack Overflow street 14
>
> Stack Overflow street 141C

Comment: Could you provide example values?

Comment: Depending on how much the values vary, this can be *very* hard. Maybe you can send the data through the Google Geocoder, which returns results like this? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#XML

Comment: Is this a MySQL database?

Comment: we cannot help you if you don't have example. Please provide an example.

Comment: Provided a couple of examples in the startpost.

Comment: @Pekka, Google Geocoder doesn't separate the street number and the addition.

Comment: How would you extract from `43th street 12` and such streets with `2nd` at the end?

Comment: Took about 10 seconds too long to answer. http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/vcw-ijt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
$str = 'Stackstreet 14a';
$matches= explode(" ", $str);
print_r($matches);
```

After that you can check each item in $matches an to detect if the item contain a digit. if the item contain a digit his number else his part of the street name. 
For example:

```
$matches= Array ( [0] => Stackstreet [1] => 14a )
```

`"Stackstreet"` - not contain a digit==>street name.

`"14a"` - contain a digit==>number.

**This is how to detect is string contain a digit:**

```
$myString="14a";
if (preg_match('/[A-Za-z].*[0-9]|[0-9].*[A-Za-z]/', $myString))
{
    echo 'Contains at least one letter and one number';
}
```

**Another way:**

According to [b01](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488557/separate-street-name-from-street-number?rq=1) :

Try this as see if it works for you:

```
$subjects = array( "street 12", "street12", "street 12a", "street12a" );
foreach( $subjects as $subject )
{
    if ( preg_match('/([^\d]+)\s?(.+)/i', $subject, $result) )
    {
       var_dump( $result );
    }
}
die_r( $result  );
```

The only part you need is this:

```
// Find a match and store it in $result.
if ( preg_match('/([^\d]+)\s?(.+)/i', $subject, $result) )
{
    // $result[1] will have the steet name
    $streetName = $result[1];
    // and $result[2] is the number part. 
    $streetNumber = $result[2];
}
```

**Credit to** [b01](https://stackoverflow.com/users/419097/b01).

Comment: This only returns the street numbers and not the names. I already found '/([^\d]+)\s?(.+)/i'. This separated the street name from the number, but not the number from the optional addition.

Comment: @Mike de Vrind I changed my answer to use explode() function to split by space;

Comment: @Mike de Vrind Did this help you?

Comment: Explode is going to catch all sorts of words.

Comment: @One Man Crew This is the post I also found. It has he reg ex I mentioned in my comment. But  with this regex the addition is still part of of house number. But I believe a combination of his regex and your if statement (This is how to detect is string contain a digit) I could make this work!

Comment: @MikedeVrind (I must be invisible.)

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ What do you mean???? according to PHP Manual: explode — Split a string by string. what is the problem ? and why to downvote?!?!

Comment: "Stack Overflow street 141C" gets you 4 strings with explode. The first example of the regex matches just about everything. The last only captures 2 phrases... so "Stack" and "Overflow street 141C"

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ  you can detect which sting contain digit: for  "Stack Overflow street 141C" you will get: Array ( [0] => Stack [1] => Overflow [2] => street [3] => 141C ). the index 3 is with digit so the final result will be $street=array[0]." ".array[1]." ".array[2]." "; $number=array[3]; very simple!

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ It does not make my answer incorrect!Is still correct

Comment: That only works for that one example. The OP said "I have a database in which the address contains both street name and street number (and possible addition like A,B,C etc)." Meaning it could be any number of things. I doubt they want to rewrite their RegEx for every line when they find one that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but the answer is meant just as funny as serious:

Where the input is:

```
<input type=text name=streetAndNumberAndExtension />
```

You really need to do:

```
<input type=text name=street />
<input type=text name=number />
<input type=text name=extension/>
```

Throwing all on 1 pile and later trying to split it will be hacky and will need manual checking all fields and fixing broken ones before being acceptable. For a programmer, not really a solution.

Comment: You are totally right. Thats the way it should be done. But I'm working on a existing webshop. I can't just start changing the database and all related code and forms.

Comment: Sure you can :) ... (Or is it closed source?) ... Anyway, then all you can have is a hacky solution at best. And you will have to accept a few misfits.

Comment: Okay okay... I Can :p But client won't pay for all that extra work :p But I think that with a good reg ex, the chance of an error will be minimal. As I mentioned in a above comment, I already found a regex that seperates the name from the number, only i'm still stuck with the addition on the number.

Comment: @MikedeVrind I don't think this would be a hacky attempt though... http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/vcw-ijt

Comment: No need to downvote this comment. When building a new webshop, this would be the right way to do it!

But unfortunately I needed to add something to an existing webshop and a client needs to pay for my time :p

@AbsoluteƵERØ Thank you :p Maybe it's a bit hacky. But the a correct regex I could be a good solution for the current problem.

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ How would you regex this existing address? Plein 40-45 12 (an address in Amsterdam)